# Как разбить JAR на отдельные файлы

Tags: java, jar

Может вопрос и неуместен на этом форуме, но тем не менее, большинство приложений состоят из исполняющего файла и дополнительных файлов, библиотек и т.п. Как мне сделать такое? У меня есть довольно большой коммерческий проект на JAVAfx и не хотелось бы того, чтобы был всего один файлик (jar), в папке с приложением, спасибо!

Comment: Вы при формировании артифакта можете указать, что будет в него входить. Можете не включать что-то и всё. Только придется пути к ресурсам подредачить, чтоб искались файлы относительно jar файла. А то наверняка они сейчас относительно классов или еще чего подобного указаны........... если через maven, то можно юзать `maven-resources-plugin` где можно определить что в jar положить а что нет...

Comment: воспользуйтесь поиском по слову `jar` здесь на сайте и там полно ответов найдете как собрать артефакт с включением только определенных вещей

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, так и сделаю! Использую maven, буду гуглить :)

Comment: Не обязательно гуглить.... Я говорю: прям тут на stackoverflow вверху вбейте в поле поиска `jar` http://i.stack.imgur.com/YlXda.jpg там все есть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я это и сделал, спасибо ;) Гуглю про maven